# Complex quantifiers in Idris?

Tags: math, types, idris, dependent-type, quantifiers

Now I know, it's possible to express quantifiers via dependent types. So I wrote a simple realization for this "for all (a, b: N): exists (c: N): c = a + b":

```
f : (a : Nat) -> (b : Nat) -> (c : Nat ** c = a + b)
f a b = (a + b ** Refl)
```

and it works.

And now I want to know, can I express this "for all (a, b: N): exists (c: N): c > a and c < b"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Nat` comparison you can use [`Data.Nat`'s](https://idris2docs.sinyax.net/data/base/docs/Data.Nat.html) `GT` (greater than), `GTE` (greater-equal than), `LT` (less than), `LTE` (less-equal than). So `GT c a` and `LT c b` for `c > a` and `c < b`.

For `and` you can just put both proofs into a tuple: `(GT c a, LT c b)`. If, for example, you would have wanted to `or` them, you could use `Either (GT c a) (LT c b)`.

Thus:

```
import Data.Nat

f : (a, b : Nat) -> (c : Nat ** (GT c a, LT c b))
```

(However, this exact example wouldn't work, as you cannot define `f`, as there is no `c` so `c > 5 and c < 5`.)